# How to setup TypeScript for Lodash/fp or Ramda curried functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, lodash, ramda.js

is there a way to set up TS for Lodash/Fp or Ramda curried functions? I know there are packages like @types/lodash and @types/ramda. But it still didn't work for curried functions.

**With curried functions I mean:**
curried: `get(path)(data)`,
not curried: `get(path, data)`

**For example we will use lodash/fp with TS.**

```
import { get } from 'lodash/fp';
const data = { person: { name: 'some text' } };
const person: string = get('person', data); //Not curried
```

In this example, TS will correctly throw the error "const person: string
Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'"

**But in this example, we will use carried get() function and TS has no issue at all:**
*I'm expecting an error*

```
import { get } from 'lodash/fp';
const data = { person: { name: 'some text' } };
const person: string = get('person')(data); //curried
```

Any ideas if is out there any solution, please? Maybe use Flow instead of TS?

Comment: it looks like Lodash/fp is deprecated. and it might not have type declarations for it.

Comment: you can look at fpts and ReScript too

Comment: You could write own typings for this. The libraries are open source and depend on the support of the community. Fix it and create a pull request.

Comment: @DanielA.White from what I know, Lodash/Fp isn't deprecated and lodash/fp types are under @types/lodash package.