# Is lodash/fp deprecated?

Tags: functional-programming, lodash, deprecated

I've not found evidence, but [a relatively recent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73403890/how-to-setup-typescript-for-lodash-fp-or-ramda-curried-functions#comment129629364_73403890) claims that [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) is deprecated.

I was therefore wondering if I'm just bad at searching.

Comment: Whoever wrote that it's deprecated was probably thinking of underscore.js, which it effectively replaced.

Comment: You'll probably find you don't need lodash anywhere near as much as you might've a few years ago; browsers have added much of the missing functionality it added.

Comment: @Enlico It's not my downvote, but IMO "is x deprecated" is off-topic on SO.

Comment: @ceejayoz Why? What would be the reason? Which close reason would fit?

Comment: @jabaa I'm of the opinion that "is library x deprecated" leads fairly inevitably to the "what replaces it?" follow-up. This question, in particular, could've just been a comment in reply to the (apparently incorrect) comment it references.

Comment: @ceejayoz Assuming the answer is "yes", this could lead to a follow-up question and follow-up questions should be avoided. But the answer is "no". No follow-up question expected. You should not ask questions in comments and Stack Overflow wants to collect all technical programming-related questions as questions with answers. You're crating a large story to try to close the question.

Comment: @ceejayoz:  [This question is being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424583/1079354).

Comment: Relevant [Github-Issue](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/5605)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if "deprecated" is the accurate term as of 5/19/23, but it basically seems that way according to this issue where the author states there's no intention of keeping lodash/fp in the upcoming rewrite of lodash.

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/5526

Answer (score 2):

Now is 2023 and the last [lodash release](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/releases) has happened 7 years ago. If you are comfortable with a dinosaur, which does some [havoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981230/lodash-unexpectedly-injects-itself-into-global-when-required-in-subdependency) in your back garden then it is your choice. But it is better to find a modern replacement.

UPDATE: Sep 2023, from [this](https://tomaszs2.medium.com/is-lodash-really-dead-wheres-lodash-5-cbdd79549565) article it seems something is cooking there. Hope it is v5 coming up. Let's see

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not deprecated. The comment is wrong.

No deprecation is mentioned in the [Lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) repository or the [Lodash/FP](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/tree/npm/fp) repository.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this answer could be improved by providing some evidence.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine What would be an evidence for the non-existence of a deprecation? The last code changes are some years old. An update of the guide could be an indication, but not an evidence.

Comment: The author responding would be evidence, but SO isn't a place to ask specific individuals questions.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be deprecated. In fact the [FP Guide](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) was updated on March 31st this year.